# After upgrading spark to 2.3.0, I get RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found

Tags: apache-spark

I just upgraded Spark to 2.3.0 from 2.1.1 and when i run a spark query in Yarn client mode, i get the below errors. Please could someone, help.

Error in force(code) :

```
  Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found

20/05/07 19:52:41 ERROR sparklyr: 
Backend (56815) failed calling getOrCreate on 14: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hadoop-yarn-client jar to your class-path and use the same version of your other hadoop jars in you pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.verion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Download the jar from [hadoop Client jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/3.0.3) of the hadoop version and place it Spark's lib folder

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am new to hadoop and spark, in which configuration file should i add the above

Comment: what build tool are you using for your project ?

Comment: This error is now resolved after i have used the correct jar files for the hadoop version but when reading data from hadoop, a new error has come up.

Comment: @mokumar1202 what is the error . plz update the question

Comment: This error is now resolved after i have used the correct jar files for the hadoop version but when reading data from hadoop, a new error has come up.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.<init>(ILorg/apache/parquet/column/ParquetProperties$WriterVersion;Z

I have found that version of the Parquet jar files is 1.8.2

Comment: and also this - ERROR sparklyr: Backend (98653) failed calling saveAsTable on 137: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: can you please post complete error stack traces in question

Comment: Is this helpful

ERROR sparklyr: Gateway (63409) failed calling saveAsTable on 1870: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.parquet.column.ParquetProperties.<init>(ILorg/apache/parquet/column/ParquetProperties$WriterVersion;Z)V
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.<init>(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:98)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.<init>(ParquetRecordWriter.java:100)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:327)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:283)

Comment: these are errors to be solved by trying multiple versions of parquet-column jars. I can't give you exact which version shall solve your problem

Comment: This is fixed now after using Parquet jars of version 1.8.3